# Getting Mockito and Powermock to throw error correctly

Tags: java, testing, mockito, powermock

I have the following code

```
@PrepareForTest({Mongo.class, XYMongo.class, DB.class})
public class XYMongoTest extends UnitTest{

String host = Play.configuration.getProperty("mongo.host");
int port = Integer.parseInt(Play.configuration.getProperty("mongo.port"));  
String name = Play.configuration.getProperty("mongo.name");

@Test
public void testRetrieveMongoDBSuccessful() throws UnknownHostException, MongoException, Exception
{
    Mongo mongoMock = mock(Mongo.class);
    DB mockDB = mock(DB.class);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(Mongo.class).withArguments(host, port).thenReturn(mongoMock);

    when(mongoMock.getDB(name)).thenReturn(mockDB);

    XYMongo.getMongoDB();

    verify(mongoMock.getDB(name));
}


@Test
public void testRetrieveMongoDBFailUnkownHost() throws Exception
{   
    try
    {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Mongo.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(Mongo.class).withArguments(host, port).thenThrow(new UnknownHostException("Test Exception"));

        XYMongo.getMongoDB();

        PowerMockito.verifyNew(Mongo.class).withArguments(host, port);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        assertEquals("Test Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

The first test passes fine and the second fails with the test error being

Failure, expected:<[Test Exception]> but was:<[ Missing method call for verify(mock) here: -> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocationcontrol.MockitoNewInvocationControl.expectSubstitutionLogic(MockitoNewInvocationControl.java:65) Example of correct verification: verify(mock).doSomething() Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods. Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified. ]>

Any ideas on how to fix this? Tried everything I can think of.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is actually coming from `testRetrieveMongoDBSuccessful()`; it looks like you've got the `verify()` not-quite-right, but Mockito can't *tell* you that until the *next* time you interact with it.

Try replacing the last line of `testRetrieveMongoDBSuccessful()`  with:

`verify(mongoMock).getDB("name");`